# How do I clear a dropdown and input field with query

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that is setup with twitter bootstrap and it's using tabs.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/DJeqm/4/

If you can see from the exmaple we have:

Edit existing assignments and create new assignments.

If you see on the tab under edit existing assignments, there is a drop down. What will happen is when the user selects an option from the drop down, I submit an ajax request that will go out and grab some information depending on which dropdown the user selected:

```
function loadQuery() {
var assign = $("#existingAssignment").val(); // Get the value of the select box so we         can build the next page
$.get('Pagetoload.cfm?tour_id=' + assign ,{},function(data){
$("#centercontent").html(data)
 })
 return false
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#NewAssignment").attr('val', '');
$("#NewPosTitle").attr('val', '');
$("#NewgetPosOff").attr('val', '');
$("#loadLink").click(loadQuery)
});
```

The jQuery that reloads the new page is working fine and it sends the information to the center div of that tab. It effectively replaces the div with the information that was returned. So now the edit existing assignment now has new values filled in.

On the other tab "Create New Assignment" There is a form that should have all of it's values set to blank.

I am trying to reset those values right before I call the loadQuery function but when I go back to the page, the values are still there.

Is there another function that I should call or do something different to set those values to " "?

TIA

Comment: When you make fiddles, you should not have `<script>` tags inside of the JavaScript section!

Comment: Ummm ... the linked jsfiddle doesn't seem to have the same code ...

Comment: No the jsfillde does not have the same code as I'm using ColdFusion and I can't accurately show how this is reloading the page. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's built in [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method!

```
$("#NewAssignment").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("#NewAssignment").val('');
$("#NewPosTitle").val('');
$("#NewgetPosOff").val('');
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I had that originally and it did not do the trick. Just tried it again, and the values are still there.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `.val()` or `.text()` of JQuery. You may want to refer here for more info about JQuery functions http://api.jquery.com/